Proving $\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (\theta_j - \theta_m)^2 \leq 2 \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (j + 1 )(\theta_{j+1} - \theta_j)^2$
Today I found in a peer-reviewed paper an inequality which I could not figure out.

Let $\theta_j\in \mathbb R$ be arbitrary, then
$ \begin{align} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (\theta_j - \theta_m)^2 \leq 2
 \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (j + 1 )(\theta_{j+1} - \theta_j)^2, \quad \text{by }
 (a+b)^2 \leq 2a^2 + 2b^2. \end{align} $

What I have tried is to use $(\theta_j - \theta_m)^2 \leq (m-j) \sum_{k=j}^{m-1}(\theta_{k+1} - \theta_k)^2$. However, this will give me
$$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (\theta_j - \theta_m)^2 \leq  \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(m-j) \sum_{k=j}^{m-1}(\theta_{k+1} - \theta_k)^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \left(\sum_{j=0}^k (m-j)\right)(\theta_{k+1} -\theta_k)^2, $$
which is completely different from the bound in the paper, and I never used $(a+b)^2 \leq 2a^2 + 2b^2$. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could clarify this for me.

Perhaps it should be $$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (\theta_j - \theta_m)^2 \leq m
\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} (j + 1 )(\theta_{j+1} - \theta_j)^2.$$

I don't think that inequality is true. Take, for example, $\theta_j = j$ for $0\le j\le m$. Then, the inequality reduces to
\begin{equation*}
\frac{m(m + 1)(2m + 1)}{6} = \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1}(m - j)^2\le 2\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} (j + 1) = 2\frac{m(m + 1)}{2},
\end{equation*}
which is not true for $m > 3$.

Thank you! In this case, should I simply delete the question? Since it is a wrong question to start with.
